# What does this means in this context ? 念写の大人しいスキル

Tags: meaning, word-usage, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english

When I'm reading a visual novel, I met with this term in a sentence  but don't understand. Hope someone can explain its meaning to me.

Context: MC is studying in an academy for people with special powers (like X-men- controls gravity, teleport...etc). He's describing 1 of his classmate's powers.

> **そういえば M のスキルは透視、念写の大人しいスキル以外にテレポートスキルがあったな……。**
> (especially the 大人しいスキル part ??)

Answer (score 3):

First consider 念写のスキル. This の is within the usage that can be translated as *of*: the skill of 念写. Here 透視 is listed as well, so without 大人しい, it is *(except) the skills of 念写 and 透視*.

For the 大人しい, it may depend on the context, but it can mean something like absence of features, extending absence of sounds (*quiet*). For example, 大人しい色 means a color that does not pop into the eyes - brown, gray, etc. An opposite is 派手な色 (I found *loud* is used similarly according to [a J-E dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%B4%BE%E6%89%8B/#je-61170)).

So the speaker categorizes extraordinary skills into 'loud' type and non-loud type, and is referring to M's skills as *the non-loud/plain skills of 透視 and 念写*. I suppose it refers to the non-dynamic nature of them in contrast to dynamic teleporting.